# Firebase popup signin popup-closed-by-user error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to use the Javascript client library for Firebase auth to sign in with a Google account and popup window. However, when I try to sign in, the signin window pops up, I select my Google account, and then it spends about 10 seconds loading (with the blue progress bar moving), then the popup window closes, and shortly after I get the following error message:

```
code: "auth/popup-closed-by-user"
message: "The popup has been closed by the user before finalizing the operation."
```

I have enabled Google signin in the authentication section of the Firebase web UI. Below is the code I am using which is pretty much directly copied from the Firebase docs. I have made no other changes to the project config. I started a new project just to test this and have simply run `firebase init`, enabling only hosting, and enabling Google signin in the authentication web UI.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>

    <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.6/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.6/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="signin">sign in</button>
    <button id="signout">sign out</button>
    <script>
      const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      const signinButton = document.querySelector("#signin");
      signinButton.addEventListener("click", () =>
        firebase
          .auth()
          .signInWithPopup(provider)
          .then(function (result) {
            console.log("result", result);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
          })
      );
      const signoutButton = document.querySelector("#signout");
      signoutButton.addEventListener("click", () =>
        firebase
          .auth()
          .signOut()
          .then(function () {
            console.log("signed out");
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
          })
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/3188.

For some users, this is resolved by adding the app domain to the list of authorized domains:
Firebase Console -> Auth -> Sign-In Method -> Authorized Domains -> Add (domain)

Answer (score 2):

For some users this may be caused by the `Firefox Containers` feature, or by the Firefox `Enhanced Tracking Protection` feature, specifically its `isolate other cross-site cookies` feature.

Answer (score 1):

Also, this may be happening because you haven't caught the error. Catching error will help to avoid the website from crashing.

```
  signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log("Logged In", result);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Caught error Popup closed");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add custom parameters to provider. Something like this:

```
const provider = new FacebookAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({ display: 'popup' });
const userCredentials = await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);
```

That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Setting this header on my development server worked for me to keep the popup open. I'm using vite with vue.

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": "/src",
    },
  },
  server: {
    headers: {
      "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy": "same-origin-allow-popups",
    }
  },
});
```

And then for it to close quickly, i had to use "Optional Chaining" operators. So that its not getting held up if either of `result` or  `credential` isn't defined.

```
async signInWithGoogle() {
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  try {
    const result = await signInWithPopup(getAuth(), provider);
    //This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    const token = result?.credential?.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    const user = result?.user;
    // Now you can use these details to update your store
    this.login(token, { data: user });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error signing in with Google: ", error);
  }
},
```